# Selecting a specific element with Selenium - Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to click this button shown after choosing an option from a drop-down menu.
This is the button I'm trying to click.
[image]

The link to the website: https://excise.wb.gov.in/CHMS/Public/Page/CHMS_Public_Hospital_Bed_Availability.aspx

The html:
[image]

I've tried using XPATH, and through visible text; nothing seems to work.
My code as of now:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://excise.wb.gov.in/CHMS/Public/Page/CHMS_Public_Hospital_Bed_Availability.aspx")
drop_dist = \
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/div[3]/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/select")
select_dist = Select(drop_dist)
select_dist.select_by_value("005")
l = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/div[3]/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/a").click()
time.sleep(30)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The locator seems fragile, use following locator and webdriverwait() to handle sync issue.

```
driver.get("https://excise.wb.gov.in/CHMS/Public/Page/CHMS_Public_Hospital_Bed_Availability.aspx")
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
select_dist =Select(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddl_District"))))
select_dist.select_by_value("005")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//a[@class='btn btn-link' and contains(., 'View Detail Break up')])[1]"))).click() //this will click the first one only.
```

You have to add following imports.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm. I just needed to add an extra `time.sleep(30)` just because after clicking the element, the automated chrome was closing in a split second.

Comment: Could you also tell me how you figured out that xpath? And why is the index [1] and not [0]?

Comment: @ProjatoChakraborty : learn more about xpath(https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/xpath-writing-cheat-sheet-tutorial-examples/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
button = driver.find_elements(By.CSS, 'a[role="button"][aria-expanded="false"]')[0]
button.click()
```

You can change the index in order to click on other elements

Comment: This threw up an error: ```raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//small[contains(text(),"View Detail Break Up")```

Comment: @ProjatoChakraborty What option do you select when you reach the webpage? Is the element sits inside an iframe element?

Comment: First the program selects an option from the dropdown options; then it's supposed to select the first "View Detail Break up".  ```<i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i><small>&nbsp;View Detail Break up</small>```